# setting height and width of BIRT viewer dynamically based on contents

Tags: jsp, birt

I constructed a report by using `BIRT` and `Data tables`. Everything is working as expected. However `height` and `width` of `BIRT viewer` aren't dynamic. They are static and hence scroll is applied. So I wrote a code to make `height` and `width` of `BIRT viewer` dynamic.

```
function resizeFrame(e,f){
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

        var winW = 1112, winH = 486;
        if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
            winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
            winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }
        if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
            winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
            winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        }
        if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
            winW = window.innerWidth;
            winH = window.innerHeight;
        }

        x[0].style.width = winW + "px";
        x[0].style.height = winH + "px";

        console.log(f,e);
    }
```

**`BIRT code is:`**

```
<birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="/sampleReport.rptdesign"
            pattern="run" height="700" width="1136" scrolling="none"
            showParameterPage="false" isHostPage="false">

        </birt:viewer>
```

Please note that height and width of BIRT viewer are `700px` and `1136px` respectively. Above code isn't making `height` and `width` dynamic.
How can I make BIRT height and width dynamic? I've added a picture for clear understanding.[image: BIRT]
As you can see in picture, it is adding vertical scrolling. How to prevent that and make height of BIRT increase based on table height?

Answer (score 1):

were you able to trigger the function you wrote from the report? I don't think so. I would take a look at the code that 'builds' the viewer and runs the report.

After the report has been build and loaded, you can trigger the a javascript function to resize the window to fit it's content.
More info here: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php

Not sure why you need this? Isn't it much easier to just open a full screen window?

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest to use hight and width in percentage(%).

Also calculate window hight and width and use same for outer div.

for inner div use hight and width 100%, so inner div will be fixed in outer div and scroll will not appear on screen.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: in rtpdesign file I cannot give %